# Which font supports the most non-roman alphabets?

Tags: fonts, localization

I am a graphic designer and I try to only have fonts installed that I'm using for a project, or for general use. I always end up uninstalling all these Thai, Chinese, Indian and other typefaces that install with Ubuntu. However, even though I can't read these alphabets, I do prefer to see them when displayed on a website (e.g. Wikipedia) than to just see boxes.

Are there one or two fonts that will cover most non-Roman alphabets? I don't mind having a couple installed.

Comment: Maybe you'd better make up your mind. ;) Why did you uninstall the default font packages in the first place?

Comment: The stated goal of the Google Noto fonts is to show as few boxes as possible (what they call tofu - hence "no tofu" -> "noto")

Comment: Noto installs a huge suite of fonts, though. I'm asking for one or two fonts that support a large number of non-western alphabets, so the fonts don't clutter up any font selection dialog.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple years trying to solve this problem. I think Noto is the way to go. It will still put a lot of fonts on your system, but since they all start with 'Noto', it's easier to browse the rest of your active fonts.

I recommend uninstalling all of ubuntu's foreign language fonts and replacing with Noto.